# deepstream message delivery gaurantees

Tags: ruby-on-rails, real-time, messaging

I have been looking at various real time message libraries but I could not find following details of them.

1) Guaranteed delivery of messages

- if a message was sent by client a - it's guaranteed that client b will receive it? (built-in ack and retry mechanisms)

2) Guaranteed order of messages

- if 2 messages were sent by client a - it's guaranteed that client b will receive them in correct order ?

I googled but didn't find answers to my questions, so I'm posting here.

I would like to know it for following libraries

- deepstream.io  https://deepstreamhub.com
- socket.io http://socket.io
- emitter.io http://emitter.io

Thanks!